# python operators = and == counter

Tags: python

i wrote a .txt file in which I put operators = and ==. I wrote a code which will count number of = and ==, but i dont get correct number.

```
lexicalClass = file.readlines()

for lex in lexicalClass:
newList = re.findall('\S+', lex)
for element in newList:
    if len(re.findall('[a-z]+|[0-9]+', element)):
        identifiers.append(re.findall('[a-z]+|[0-9]+', element))
        
num = len(re.findall('\=', element))
if int(num):
    if int(num) % 2 == 1:
        for i in range(int((num-1)/2)):
            equal.append('==')
        assignment.append('=')
    else:
        for i in range(int(num/2)):
            equal.append('==')
        
print(str(len(equal)))
print(str(len(assignment)))
```

My .txt file : `a == b  a = b c = d`

And as you can see my output should be 1 and 2, but im getting 0 in both.

Comment: The indentation is off. Please fix. As you know, indentation is critical for Python.

Comment: Your logic seems to be incorrect, having even number of `=` doesn't say that there are only `==`, it could also be two `=`

Comment: When using regex, always use raw strings. Spec is unclear. What does `===` count as? Three `=` and two `==`, one `=` and one `==` or neither? Looks like you're parsing a source code file. What if it contains `==` inside a string that would normally be ignored by a compiler? If you're parsing code, regex likely won't get you too far. Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: why are you escaping the `=` in `num = len(re.findall('\=', element))`? Also, `len()` always returns an `int`, you don't need to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```py
one_equals = r"(?<!=)=(?!=)"  # a "=" not followed or preceded by a =
two_equals = r"(?<!=)==(?!=)"  # "==" not followed or preceded by a =

assignment = 0
equals = 0
with open("yourfilename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        equal += len(re.findall(one_equals, line))
        assignment += len(re.findall(two_equals, line))
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python source code, the correct way to do this is with the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), using [`ast.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.walk) and counting instances of the [`ast.Assign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Assign) and [`ast.Eq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Eq) nodes:

```py
import ast

with open("yourfilename.txt") as f:
    parsed_source = ast.parse(f.read())
    nodes = list(ast.walk(parsed_source))
    equals = sum(isinstance(n, ast.Eq) for n in nodes)
    assignments = sum(isinstance(n, ast.Assign) for n in nodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care about the efficiency of algorithm, this is a fairly simple solution:

```py
file = open("asd.txt")

total_double_eq_count = 0
total_single_eq_count = 0

#iterate over the lines of file
for line in file:
    #count of '=='s in the line
    double_eq_count = line.count("==")
    #count of '='s which are not followed by an another '='.
    single_eq_count = line.count("=") - 2*double_eq_count

    total_double_eq_count += double_eq_count
    total_single_eq_count += single_eq_count
    
print(total_double_eq_count)
print(total_single_eq_count)
```

But this is relatively fast compared to a equivalent python code since we are using builtin methods for string processing. At least on small inputs.